# Change font programmatically for GTK3 TextView (quickly-widgets TextEditor)

Tags: application-development, quickly, pygi

In an app using PyGI and GTK3, I'm trying to let the user set the font family and size in a TextView through my app's settings dialog. In PyGI the TextView object has "set" methods for several properties, but not for font properties. I can set the font family via CSS using a CSS style provider. But I can't change that CSS dynamically to respect the font selected by a user. So how can I do this? (Note that the widget in question is actually the TextEditor from the quickly-widgets package and I'm using Quickly to build the app.)

Edit to clarify: I'm not wedded to using CSS, that just seems to be GTK's preferred approach. What I'm hoping for is a method of some kind, like GtkTextView.setFontProperties() or something like that. I can't find anything like that for font properties.

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the font in a textview using GTK+'s built-in button and dialog for this, `Gtk.FontButton()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import Gtk

class TextViewWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_default_size(400, 400)

        main_vbox = Gtk.VBox(homogeneous=False, spacing=0)
        self.window.add(main_vbox)

        self.tview = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        main_vbox.add(self.tview)

        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        self.textbuffer.set_text("Here is a text view.")
        self.textview.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.WORD)

        self.tview.add(self.textview)

        self.font_button = Gtk.FontButton()
        self.font_button.connect('font-set', self.on_font_set)
        main_vbox.pack_start(self.font_button, False, False, 0)

        self.window.show_all()
        self.window.connect('destroy', lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())

    def on_font_set(self, widget):
        font_description = widget.get_font_desc()
        print "You chose: " + widget.get_font()
        self.textview.modify_font(font_description)

def main():
    app = TextViewWindow()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My demo:

[image: demo]

Built-in dialog:

[image: picker]

Comment: Interesting... Is it necessary to import Pango though?  I don't see you explicitly call anything from it. Also that's a really horrid font selection dialog...

Comment: I started writing that before I decided to actually throw the demo together. Pango isn't actually used. Fixed above.

Comment: That's great. Thanks (and sorry for the delayed accept).

Comment: Just a note, modify_font is deprecated now in favor of override_font for Gtk.

Comment: Keep in mind this is marked as deprecated, you should use custom CSS style, through an application-specific StyleProvider and a CSS style class.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use texttags to do this, but I'm not sure it's the "best" way.

First you would select all the text, [here's](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/textview.html#tags) the page from the readthedocs site on applying tags.

And [here's](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkTextTag.html#GtkTextTag--font) a list of properties from the C/C++ reference.

Just adding this on... I recently needed to do something similar, and I had to do a little looking to come up with this snippet:

```
self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
self.textview.override_font(
    Pango.font_description_from_string('DejaVu Sans Mono 12')
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @aking1012. But I am really looking for something lower-level. If the CSS style providers are now supposed to be the standard way of styling GTK widgets, it seems to me that there should still be a way of setting that style information dynamically.

Comment: That's fair, but you want to: a)set dynamically and b)use css.  Well, setting dynamically involves a function call anyway and making a load of CSS files to switch between seems counter-intuitive to me.  I would set it either a)once in the glade file or b)through function calls.

Comment: Yeah, @aking1012, I see what you mean. It's just that the GTK3 api (and PyGI) provides methods to set most style features globally for a widget object, even if you have defaults set in your CSS provider. It seems very odd to me that there isn't something similar for font properties -- so I'm hoping that I've just missed something. Tags are meant, I think, for working with portions of text, not for setting global styles on the widget.

Comment: I see your point as well.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to solve your problem, but there's GtkFontChooserWidget http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFontChooserWidget.html Maybe you can use it somehow.

Comment: Keep in mind this is marked as deprecated, you should use custom CSS style, through an application-specific StyleProvider and a CSS style class.